# Is there any way to convert Transport for London's TransXChange data to GTFS?

Tags: gtfs, transit

There used to be a tool by Google called Transxchange2GoogleTransit, but the project looks abandoned. It's not working with the latest **NaPTAN** data format which was released two years ago.

Comment: There's this: https://github.com/Transporter-Project/transxchange-to-gtfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there isn't. We ended up writing our own solution. If interested [contact us](https://github.com/urbanmassage).

Comment: I am looking into something similar... What was the reason that you did not choose [TransXChange2GTFS](https://github.com/jpf18/TransXChange2GTFS) and implemented something new? Was the only reason that it seems to be abandoned or was there some missing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This project appears to solve this problem, providing a simple way to produce combined GTFS data from TfL's Unified API:

https://github.com/CommuteStream/tflgtfs.git